# Names of list objects in RStudio multiple viewing

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to view multiple objects of a list in RStudio using `View` function from `utils` package.

Suppose the list cosists of some data frames as follow:

```
y<-list(a=data.frame(1,2),b= data.frame(2,3),c=data.frame(3,4))
```

To view `a` and `b` and `c` at once I used:

```
lapply(y, View)
```

This succeeded in viewing all objects in y, however the names of these objects in the viewer are not `a`, `b` and `c` but rather `X[[1L]]`, `X[[2L]]` and `X[[3L]]`.

The function has a `title` argument with "Defaults to name of x prefixed by Data:." according to the documentation. So it is supposed to give the name of x instead of the above. Any idea how to get this work?

I am on Mac 10.11.1 and RStudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over the names of `y` instead, that gives you a nice string to feed to the title-argument:

```
lapply(names(y),function(x) View(y[x],title=x))
```